# how to restrict duplication of array in php?

Tags: php

i am searching file using following code but in output it shows result 5 times.
this is the code. if something wrong in the code then plz tell.

```
$root1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 

$directory =
$root1.'/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/';

$it = new
RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));

while($it->valid()) 
{ 
    if(!$it->isDot())
    {
        $files =glob($directory.$it->getSubPath().'/*.jpg');
        print_r($files);
    }
    $it->next();
}
```

& the output is :-

```
Array ( [0] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports19.jpg [1] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports21.jpg [2] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports22.jpg [3] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports3.jpg ) Array ( [0] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports19.jpg [1] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports21.jpg [2] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports22.jpg [3] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports3.jpg ) Array ( [0] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports19.jpg [1] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports21.jpg [2] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports22.jpg [3] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports3.jpg ) Array ( [0] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports19.jpg [1] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports21.jpg [2] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports22.jpg [3] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports3.jpg ) Array ( [0] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports19.jpg [1] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports21.jpg [2] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports22.jpg [3] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports3.jpg ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/pratikg88/matromonial24.jpg )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling `print_r` every time a new file is added. move it after your while loop

```
$files = array();
while($it->valid()) {
    if(!$it->isDot()) {
        $files = array_merge($files, glob($directory.$it->getSubPath().'/*.jpg'));
    }
    $it->next();
}
print_r($files);
```

your array is fine, you are simply printing it too often

**edit**

i assume you want to retrieve all jpg files from your directories, there's a good example in on of the comments on  [RecursiveDirectoryIterator manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228) on php.net:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/project/'));
$Regex = new RegexIterator($it, '/^.+\.jpg$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

quote:

> $Regex will contain a single index array for each PHP file.

Comment: hey dude its not working if i add specific filename
if i put print statement in while loop then it works but the duplication problem occur again

Comment: @pritkg88: oh, i now see another error, you were clearing the $files array with each iteration, see my edit

Comment: hey dude i got it it would be like this

$i=0;
$num=1;
while($it->valid() and $i<$num) 
{
    if(!$it->isDot()) {
        $files = glob($directory.$it->getSubPath().'/*.jpg');
  print_r($files);
  $i++;
    }
    
 $it->next();
}

Comment: thanks for help & giving your valuable time to solve my query.